# How to share a dictionary between multiple processes in python without locking

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to share a huge dictionary (around 1 gb in size) between multiple processs, however since all processes will always read from it. I dont need locking.

Is there any way to share a dictionary without locking?

The multiprocessing module in python provides an Array class which allows sharing without locking by setting
    lock=false
however There is no such option for Dictionary provided by manager in multiprocessing module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in fact the dict on a Manager has no locks at all! I guess this is true for the other shared object you can create through the manager too. How i know this? I tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(d):
    for i in range(10000):
        d['blah'] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()
    d['blah'] = 0
    procs = [ Process(target=f, args=(d,)) for _ in range(10) ]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    print d
```

If there were locks on `d`, the result would be `100000`. But instead, the result is pretty random and so this is just a nice illustration why locks are needed when you modify stuff ;-)

So just go ahead and use `manager.dict()`.

Comment: I see the race condition: d['blah'] += 1 is actually d['blah'] = d['blah'] + 1 which breaks down to get d['blah'], add 1, and then store in d['blah']. In that time the other process could have changed it. The manager in this case is just providing a proxy to access the dict. Really should use the manager to also create a lock between the reading and the adding back to the dict.