# Alternative to Python Multiprocessing Manager dict for large read only store

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using Multiprocessing with a large (~5G) read-only dict used by processes. I started by passing the whole dict to each process, but ran into memory restraints, so changed to use a Multiprocessing Manager dict (after reading this [How to share a dictionary between multiple processes in python without locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936626/how-to-share-a-dictionary-between-multiple-processes-in-python-without-locking) )

Since the change, performance has dived. What alternatives are there for a faster shared data store?  The dict has a 40 character string key, and 2 small string element tuple data.

Comment: Have found that I can simply have the dictionary as a global, and use Threading instead of Multiprocessing. Seems simple, not sure if I've missed something - it appears to work

Comment: Sorry for kicking up this old thread - Thread and multiprocessing is two entirely different things. Threads will not start up new processes and allow multicore execution, opposed to multiprocessing which will allow you to start new processes and compute on several cores in parallel. - It might be faster for small projects to avoid the multiprocessing altogether, as starting up this method might involve a bigger performance hit than just dealing with data in serial as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Use a memory mapped file. While this might sound insane (performance wise), it might not be if you use some clever tricks:

1. Sort the keys so you can use binary search in the file to locate a record
2. Try to make each line of the file the same length ("fixed width records")

If you can't use fixed width records, use this pseudo code:

```
Read 1KB in the middle (or enough to be sure the longest line fits *twice*)
Find the first new line character
Find the next new line character
Get a line as a substring between the two positions
Check the key (first 40 bytes)
If the key is too big, repeat with a 1KB block in the first half of the search range, else in the upper half of the search range
```

If the performance isn't good enough, consider writing an extension in C.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but that sounds like a ton more work for me than:
"if x in mydic". It's been suggested to use threads instead and a global, so will look at that.

Comment: Well, the first step will be to find out why it's slow. Is the problem the process startup time, the sharing of the dict, dict access?

Comment: thanks again, but I think you're assuming I have a lot of spare time to investigate the inner workings of python standard modules :)  

Have found that a global and threading instead of multiprocessing works

Comment: How about using [one of the profilers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to have Python tell you where it spends most of its time? :-)